# Bejeweled Clone flame gem upward movement troubles

Tags: c#, xna

So, this is an interesting problem. I'm making a Bejeweled 3 clone with extra stuff, and I can't figure out how to make the gems above a flame gem explosion move upwards; the middle column moves upward farther than the outer two columns(a normal flame gem explosion is 3x3).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
for (int gy = i - 1; gy <= i + 1; gy++)
{
    if (gy >= 0 && gy < gems.GetLength(0))
    {
        for (int gx = j; gx >= 0; gx--)
        {
            if (gy == i)
            {
                gems[gy, gx].MoveTowardsPosition(gems[gx, gy].Position.Swap() + new Vector2(0, -70), gemMoveSpeed * 1.8f, true, softMove: true);
            }
            else gems[gy, gx].MoveTowardsPosition(gems[gx, gy].Position.Swap() + new Vector2(0, -45), gemMoveSpeed * 1.8f, true, softMove: true);
        }
    }
}
```

The MoveTowardsPosition() method works fine in other places. This is not the problem. What the problem is is that I can't get the gems to move upwards(and in the correct location; i.e, they either move sideways, oddly, or upwards but in the wrong position. Also, i and j are the coordinates of the center of the flame gem explosion.

The other thing I should probably mention is that the visual position is separate from the position in the Gem array (gems[,]), and that the visual position is y, x whereas the gem array is x, y. I don't know how this arose, but it would be quite intensive to fix it.

Oh, and the Swap() extension method simply swaps the values in a Vector2.

If you need more information, just say so. This is my first time posting a question here, so if I've missed something, please tell me.

Comment: _"The other thing I should probably mention is that the visual position is separate from the position in the Gem array (gems[,]), and that the visual position is y, x whereas the gem array is x, y"_  - Well that would be the first thing I would fix.

Comment: @MickyDuncan I did say it would be intensive to fix, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally figured it out. Yay for persistence! Here's the code:

```
for (int gy = j - 1; gy <= j + 1; gy++)
{
    if (gy >= 0 && gy < gems.GetLength(0))
    {
        for (int gx = i; gx >= 0; gx--)
        {
            if (gy == j)
            {
                gems[gx, gy].MoveTowardsPosition(gems[gy, gx].Position.Swap() + new Vector2(0, -70), gemMoveSpeed * 1.8f, true, softMove: true);
            }
            else gems[gx, gy].MoveTowardsPosition(gems[gy, gx].Position.Swap() + new Vector2(0, -45), gemMoveSpeed * 1.8f, true, softMove: true);
            moveTimer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Turned out I had to not only reverse the gy and gx, but ALSO the i and j. I haven't fixed the swapped visual position/array position yet. I might do that in the future.